# notify user when any SMS modified from any SMS apps

Tags: android, service, sms, contentobserver, background-service

I am devloping a simple app that notifies the user when the SMS modified from any application
I am using content observer 
the problem is that I want to run it even if my app is off so if my app is off and some user mark a SMS as read he should get notfication that 1 SMS modified

here is my code

```
public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver
{
    SMSLogger smsLogger;
    Context context;

    public SMSObserver(SMSLogger smsLogger, Context context) {

        super(new Handler());
        this.context=context;
        this.smsLogger = smsLogger;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {

        super.onChange(selfChange);
        smsLogger.querySMS(context);
    }
}




public class SMSLogger {
    protected void querySMS(Context context) {
        Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
       /* cur.moveToNext(); // this will make it point to the first record, which is the last SMS sent
        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")); //content of sms
        String add = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")); //phone num
        String time = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date")); //date
        String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol")); //protocol*/

        Toast.makeText(context, "Data Changed CHECK SMS" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    /*logging action HERE...*/
    }
}
```

and here is the registration code

any idea where to add these lines of code so the user always got notified when any SMS updated ?

```
  Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Data Changed CHECK SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final Uri SMS_STATUS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        SMSLogger sl= new SMSLogger();

        SMSObserver smsSentObserver = new SMSObserver(sl, this.getBaseContext());
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(SMS_STATUS_URI, true, smsSentObserver);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Create a service and let it run on the foreground to avoid the random killing by the system

```
private void startServiceAsForeground() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyServiceService.this, targetActivity.class);
        startForeground(ONGOING_NITIFICATION_ID, creatOngoingNotificationObject(getString(R.string.ongoing_message_ok), intent));

    }

    private void updateServiceForegroundMessage(String message, Intent intent) {
        startForeground(ONGOING_NITIFICATION_ID, creatAntiDistractionOngoingNotificationObject(message, intent));
    }

    private android.app.Notification creatOngoingNotificationObject(String messageBody, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyServiceService.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_gray)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true).setContentText(messageBody);
        // Intent intent = new Intent(MainService.this, intentClass );
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyServiceService.this, 0, intent, 0);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        return mBuilder.build();
    }
```

And insert your code to the service and then you are guaranteed to intercept any incomming/outgoing message even if your application is not on the foreground because your service will be running all the time and the user will be aware of it .